# How can I add dynamic images to page headers based on headlines?

Tags: microsoft-word

[image: I want to]

*Version: Microsoft Word 2016*

Here you can see, that my headline 9 (and all other headlines, too) have an image as part of the headline and the headline is also displayed in the page header.

Everything works as I want it except one thing: The headline is displayed without the image in the page header.

**How can I have the image displayed in the page header?**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about writing, but is asking for help with software.

Comment: @KenMohnkern: We have tags for Word and other word processors specifically because we do give help to questions about using such software.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @Chenmunka

Answer (score 1):

As per Microsoft, you will need to add the image manually to the header for that page:

> Go to Insert > Header or Footer > Blank (or a simple template).
> Double-click [Type here] in the header or footer area.
> Select Pictures or Online Pictures and then select your picture.
> Select Close Header and Footer or press Esc to exit.
> For more on headers and footers, see Headers and footers in Word.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-images-to-a-header-or-footer-6116c691-9d34-4535-b4c4-1d20784e7e1d